# magento 2 catalog:images:resize - Notice error

Tags: magento2, image, thumbnail

I have strange error in magento when trying to regenerate thumbs:

```
$ php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

> Notice: Undefined index: Magento\Catalog\Model\Product in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mini-minicart-mobile/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php
>   on line 232

What is wrong?

Comment: I just got the same error, any chance you found the problem to this issue?

Comment: Just commented this line for now :)

Comment: @LucasD .. you should not change the core file. just changing deploy mode while resizing will allow you to perform.

Comment: this was only temporary for one resize images, no sense to waste more time for this

Comment: From my understanding so far, is that if you happen to call the image resize while a re-index is occurring it can cause this error. If you wait until your indexing is complete, and re-run, it will execute with no errors.

Answer (score 3):

I attribute this solution to Spyrule.

From my understanding so far, is that if you happen to call the image resize while a re-index is occurring it can cause this error. If you wait until your indexing is complete, and re-run, it will execute with no errors. – Spyrule May 12 at 15:42

Solution:

> 1)Reindex -> bin/magento indexer:reindex
>   2)Resize again ->
>   bin/magento catalog:image:resize

P.S -> Use necessary privileges where necessary.

Comment: I tried it but still error :(

Answer (score 0):

Check your deploy mode. Set the deploy mode to developer

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

This will allow you to resize images without any notice. And switch back to the production mode.

Thanks

Comment: Switching repeatedly between production and developer mode can cause all sorts of other problems including broken compilation strings. This is NOT a recommended method to resolve this problem.

Comment: I think you did not get the issue actually. It is not supposed to do regularly. `$ php bin/magento catalog:images:resize` need to be ran once after the up-gradation to 2.1.6 for your existing product images only.

Comment: Except if you clear/reset your cache, it needs to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

revise your magento folder permissions

```
chown -R webuser.webgroup /your/magento/folder/
```

flush cache

```
php bin/magento cache:clean ; php bin/magento cache:flush
```

this must be enough

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same error. As a workaround, you can remove(backup) the pub/media/catalog/product/cache folder and run the command, so it will run without an error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/128871)

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post. It didn't make sense even to me when I read it back. Learning outcome: do not answer any post at 2 am ;)

Comment: No problem. You can give example or step by step procedure to explain the work flow also given a better idea to all :).